# "The requested resource (/Hello/) is not available." in Eclipse

Tags: java, servlets

I made a simple Hello World Application using Servlet in eclipse IDE With Tom cat Server 6.0.
But it gives the following error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP Status 404 - /Hello/

type Status report

message /Hello/

description The requested resource (/Hello/) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.13
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using eclipse indigo version....Which version is better for web based application development???
I'm really confused. What necessary settings are required for creating web based applications using Servlets in eclipse IDE?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're focusing on Eclipse as the problem - it's more likely specific to your servlet application.

Comment: Give simple hello world example with Java file code n web.XML file code . . n my problem is wrote Java code n web.XML code was automatically generated with servlet mapping bt still its nt running n showing requested resource nt found . .plz guide abt web.XML code . .what exactly require in web.XMl??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure your tomcat and eclipse working well,but not your application.check if your route is right.for example,the servlet register in the web.xml and the jsp locaiton.

Answer (score 0):

This not a issue on Eclips setting. This about your mapping file for web application.Please check with  and  tags in web.xml file.
In  tag you can find  tag. in this tag you have to give proper path of your servlet (Like  packageName.servlet Calss Name)

Comment: I tried bt its nt working . .n .web.XML file is automatically generated n servlet mapping n servlet classes are correctly specified ...

Comment: If u wl give me an example then I wl understand better . . suppose hello.Java is a servlet n package is com.hello.helloservlet then wht should be require in web.XML? ?